# How to guess a solution of an ODE when the LHS includes cosine?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We've been taught that we can guess the solution of DE when we have a "special RHS" but nobody told us anything about the LHS so my question is wheather we can guess the solution when the LHS doesn't include just constants with a function and its derivatives but includes also functions like cosine etc.

For example:

$$\dot {y} + \cos (t) y = \sin(2t)$$

I tried to follow the steps I would do when guessing the solution and I ended up with:

$$2A \cos(t) + A \sin(2t) \cos(t) = \sin(2t)$$

where for:

$$\cos(t): A=0$$
$$\sin(2t):A=1$$
$$\cos(2t):A=0$$

which doesn't make sense.

Are there any special steps to follow when the LHS includes functions like cosine or is it just not possible to geuss the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: A first-order differential equation such as this has an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homogeneous equation
$$y'+\cos(t)y=0 \implies y=C e^{-\sin (t)}$$ Now, variation of parameters gives
$$C' e^{-\sin (t)}=\sin(2t)\implies C'=2 \sin(t)\cos(t)e^{\sin (t)}$$ Change variable $u=\sin(t)$ to get
$$C'=2u e^u\implies C=2 e^u (u-1)+K$$

Answer (score 0):

Computing an integrating factor $$\mu=e^{\int \cos(t)dt}=e^{\sin(t)}$$ multiplying both sides with that factor then we get
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\sin(t)}y(t)\right)=e^{\sin(t)}\sin(2t)$$ 
Can you finish?